# Crash/freeze during car chase in Lair of the Shadow Broker (Mass Effect 2)

Tags: technical-issues, mass-effect-2

Early in the *Lair of the Shadow Broker* DLC, at the end of the car chase on Ilium, there is a cutscene where you ram the car of the Asari you are chasing.

During this cutscene, the game freezes, screen goes black and stays that way (though the music continues briefly).

I have tried all the solutions given online for ME2 crashes:

- Steam's "verify game files" feature (to fix corrupt files)
- Change Audio device settings to 16bit 44khz
- Run game Borderless Windowed (instead of fullscreen)
- Run game in Windows 7 compatibility mode
- Add the command line argument -nomoviestartup
- Re-running the installer exe for the *Lair of the Shadow Broker* DLC

Any other ideas?

(I wrote this issue into pc gaming wiki too : https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_2#Crash_during_vehicle_chase_on_Illium so no point suggesting I try there...)

(i5-2500, R9 280x, 8GB RAM, 5.1ch sound, tried both 1920x1080 and 800x600, graphical settings maxed out and 'minned out').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the only solution that worked was to obtain an, ahem, alternate copy of the game, that included all the DLC.

That version simply worked without any if this timewasting and fuss EA put me through as a paying customer.

Due to the [posting guidelines](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I won't give details, but the particular version I used was packaged by a volunteer named "Mr DJ" (to help you google it, if needed).

(If anyone else has a better answer to this issue please feel free to post it, for the benefit of others).

Answer (score 1):

Try decreasing resolution. When you decide to do something, like crash, the game quickly processes a lot of data to make this work, high graphics only add to the confusion of this. I had the same problem and this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this did not help (I was able to get down as far as 800x600, and turned all the effects/settings off/down, like AF and shadows etc, and tried both windowed and fullscreen).

Answer (score 0):

I just tabbed out (on full-screen) right before the cut-scene usually crashed. Maybe I was lucky, but worth trying if the alternative is re-downloading etc.

Answer (score -2):

I changed fullscreen to windowed and it helped me to avoid the crash

Comment: The OP mentions he already tried that (or fullscreen windowed, which would have had the same effect).